# Issue with ForEach Loop in C#

Tags: c#, loops

I am trying to include a second foreach loop to pull values from a list within an object but I am having issues trying to do this.

Here is the code

```
private List<Opportunity> CreateOpportunities(Basket basket)
    {
        var opps = new List<Opportunity>();

        foreach (var orderLine in basket.OrderLines)
        {
            opps.Add(new Opportunity()
            **{**
                DelegateList = new Delegates
                {
                    foreach (var delegates in orderLine.DelegatesList)
                    {
                        FirstName = delegates.FirstName,
                        LastName = delegates.LastName,
                        Email = delegates.Email
                    }
                },

                CourseId = new CourseBooking
                {
                    Id = orderLine.CourseId
                },
                Quantity = orderLine.Quantity,
                EventId = new EventBooking
                {
                    Id = orderLine.EventId
                },
                EventItemDecimalPrice = orderLine.Price,

                TaxType = new TaxType
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "UK VAT",
                    Rate = orderLine.VatRate
                },
                RegionCode = orderLine.RegionId
            });
        }

        return opps;
    }
```

What I need to achieve is that the foreach loops in each orderLine and then within that orderLine there is a list class and a foreach to loop through this, pulling the value out and declaring against FirstName, LastName and Email

Currently its not letting me create the foreach and getting warnings saying it expects a ; or } before the foreach.
Any help would be great.

Edit: Delegate Constructor:

```
public class Delegates
{
    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Edit: Opportunity (DelegateList Class)

```
public class Opportunity
{
    [JsonProperty("event")]
    public EventBooking EventId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("course")]
    public CourseBooking CourseId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the price per person, NOT the total of the opportunity
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("price")]
    public decimal EventItemDecimalPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tax_type")]
    public TaxType TaxType { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string RegionCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("delegates")]
    public List<Delegates> DelegateList { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: You should remove the semi colon `;` from the inner `for-each` loop

Comment: You should create a Delegates constructor with orderLine as parameter.

Comment: The inner foreach is inside the object initializer. That doesn't make sense

Comment: Please could you show us the `Delegates` type? You can't write a `foreach` loop inside an object initializer like that.

Comment: Also I am not sure why you are initializing `Delegates()` twice and that too with a `for-each` in one of them and the other being empty.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions:
i've removed the semicolo
I've added the delegates constructor that I have
I've put ** by the { that is where the code is complaining
I've removed the duplicates Delegates() this was errant code that I had forgotten to remove

Comment: Along with `Delegates` please post the `DelegatesList` type

Comment: @SouvikGhosh I've added Opportunity.CS which has the DelegateList class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Linq's Select :

```
opps.Add(new Opportunity()
{
    DelegateList = orderLine.DelegatesList
       .Select(orderLineDelegate => new Delegates
       {            
            FirstName = orderLineDelegate.FirstName,
            LastName = orderLineDelegate.LastName,
            Email = orderLineDelegate.Email
       })
       .ToList(),

    CourseId = ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative suggestion - works up until newDelegates which is error'ing with "the name newDelegates does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Figured out that newDelegates should be new Delegates (missing space). delegates however is pointing to OrderDelegate delegates rather than OrderLine DelegateList and as such it can't find FirstName in the context of delegates

Comment: It was because i had not opened OrderDelegate as a public class.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is you are putting a `for-each` loop inside the object initialization. You should move your inner `for-each` loop before you are initializing `DelegateList`. Something like-

```
foreach (var orderLine in basket.OrderLines)
{
    var firstName;
    var lastName;
    var email;

    List<DelegateList> delegates = new List<DelegateList>();

    foreach (var delegates in orderLine.DelegatesList)
    {
        delegates.Add(new Delegates{firstName = delegates.FirstName,lastName = delegates.LastName,email = delegates.Email});
    }

    opps.Add(new Opportunity()
    {//...
```

Then initialize the `DelegateList` with the List populated above in the inner loop-

```
DelegateList = delegates;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The first variable is now saying var does not exist in the current context.

I'm also having the issue where the var delegates in orderLine.DelegatesList isn't linking delegates to the  List<OrderDelegate> DelegatesList and just defining it as a local variable therefore delegates.FirstName is error'ing with object does not contain definition

Comment: Also, would the foreach overwrite itself and only populate the last entry in the list as FirstName?

The summary of the code is that there is 1 orderLine but potentially multiple delegates for 1 orderline so the opportunity should be including each orderline with delegates included linked to their own orderline

Comment: @PaulAlmond Sorry, the inner `for-each` should be just after the outer `for-each`. I have modified the code please check.

Comment: Yes it would override the value since the inner loop is not storing the data. It is just copying/instantiating the field variable. If you all the values, you can use a List collection to store them.

Comment: Okay thats fixed the first bug - it's now error'ing with implicilty type variables must be initialised and I also still have the issue about calling the DelegatesList object

Comment: I do need all the values in the DelegatesList for each orderLine to be included in the opps

Comment: Thanks for your help - i've gone with bemmelding's suggestion as I think LINQ may be the cleaner solution